# Java: Class files containing source code?

Tags: java, .class-file

I was inspecting the class file format since I wanted to add source code to the class file (which was possible in early Java versions) but all I found was a SourceFile attribute and the SourceDebug attribute. I was looking for the complete source code of the class to be bundled with the class file to ease the post-processing pipeline.

Does anyone know if my memories are wrong or how I can bundle the complete source code of a class within the class file so that I do not have to look up for the java-file when I want to check the source code?

Is there a compiler switch to do that?

Javac has a -g option adding additional debug information. Can someone tell me whats are the information it adds? Without the -g switch it generates lines of code index and source file information.

The main problem I have is generate a class file but only have a reference to a source file that might change. I want simply to bundle up source and class file.

In maven I can simply copy over all the source files to the target directory but would might be incompatible with Eclipse, IntelliJ and NetBeans IDE (and what not)... .

Comment: I believe you can bundle up sources and classes in a jar.

Comment: If you use maven, it es very easy: [link](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html). The source code is bundled in an extra jar which can be downloaded independently. I can say from my own experience, that eclipse integrates this feature well, i.e. you can see the source code of any external jar as if it was directly in the jar.

Comment: But basically there is no simple way to add java sources to class files directly?

Comment: @Martin - why would you want to? Stuffing them into the classfile is a horrible hack, while leaving them as seperate files in the jar is both simpler and compatible with a lot more tools.

Comment: @Antimony I completely agree with you. For me the maven sulution I mentioned above is completely ok. The one who wants the code in the classfile is Martin Kersten.

Comment: @Antimony - I need to have both the class files and the sources. The problem with it is that I want to synchronize both to remote locations. Stuffing them in a jar means that in between I or another process can change those. Also if you have multiple versions of the class laying around you have to be quite sure what source code you discover and so on. I have some additional ways to ensure the code is quite the same by parsing the source and compare it with the lines of code information of each method (and every statement I can safely parse like for loops and whiles, ifs and returns etc).

Comment: Anything that can change source in the jar can also change source in the classfiles in the jar.

Comment: It is not the jar that I am concerned with but the process of the compilation. You have a multi step process but no step ensures that the source files have not yet being changed. While you alter class files there can be a build going on leaving a window open where the source files are manipulated in a way making it inconsistent with the class file being already compiled. This is a weak spot in the build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I found is defining a new class-file attribute (which is legal) that contains the source. Since the source is huge when compared to the class file, the content might be best compressed (yielding a 1:5 to 1:10 ratio).

This way the class file and the sources stay bundled.

The JVM specification guarantees that every JVM/Tool has to ignore unknown attributes.

I will invest into a wrapper of javac application, that ensures the source was not modified during compilation (and if yes, redo the compilation process) and after compilation is done adding the source code as a class-file attribute.

Since this will be incompatible to the IDE-build cycle of Eclipse (and most likely IntelliJ and NetBeans) it will also require a special post processor.

So integration will also require alternatives to the JavaBuilder.

Once the source code is attached to the class file in question it is very easy to do a lot of advanced stuff with it that helps with both maintaining and managing code. For me its important that the source code and a class stay together and the source information is a 100% percent equal to the source code it was compiled from.

Answer (score 0):

Using a decompiler will also provide a way to extract a useful representation of the source code since most decompiler will value the lines of code information and position the decompiled structures accordingly within the source code.

Since some scenarios will require access to comments and a correct representation on a char by char level, the decompiler would be a second rate solution.